# Images not appearing in canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I'm currently creating or at least trying to create a very simple canvas element. You should have the option to choose 1 out of 2 images. When you click one of the two images it should appear in the canvas? But I cant get it to work?

I am sure the images are correctly named.

Is there anyone able to help me?

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("mijnCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var welkBestek = document.getElementById("fotos");

var tafelkleedKleur="#ff0000"; 
function tekenAlles(){
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            //bord
            context.drawImage(bordPlaatje,0,25);

            //bestek
            if(welkBestek == "mesvork") {
                context.drawImage(mesvorkPlaatje,0,25);
            }
            else if (welkBestek == "stokjes") {
                context.drawImage(stokjesPlaatje,0,25);
            }
}

window.onload = function() {
tekenAlles();
}

function verander() {
    tafelkleedKleur = document.getElementById("tafelkleed").value;
    tekenAlles();
}

var bordPlaatje = new Image(); 
bordPlaatje.src='bord.png';

var mesvorkPlaatje = new Image(); 
mesvorkPlaatje.src='img/afbeelding1.jpg';

var stokjesPlaatje = new Image(); 
stokjesPlaatje.src='img/afbeelding2.jpg';
</script>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: This answer shows little or no research effort. Please, create a working example on the web via jsfiddle or the like and try to verify that the images are being linked to correctly.

Comment: Next times, plz don't translate code to Dutch. Just a few understand Dutch. Always code in English so you can share code, like here @ SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code example, the script is looking for an image `bord.jpg` that are in the same folder as the HTML

```
var bordPlaatje = new Image(); 
bordPlaatje.src='bord.png';
```

While mesvorkPlaatje & stokjesPlaatje referenced as an subfolder.

```
var mesvorkPlaatje = new Image(); 
mesvorkPlaatje.src='img/afbeelding1.jpg';

var stokjesPlaatje = new Image(); 
stokjesPlaatje.src='img/afbeelding2.jpg';
```

are you having a sub folder img/ ? are the images available?

*ps: try to use English in your code, i made the same error @ start, while it is logical for you, does not mean it is logical for another person working on your code.*